# VMWare Workstation 8 SLES Linux Host and Guest, vlan not being passed through?

Tags: virtual-machine, vlan

I'm running VMware Workstation 8 on SLES 11 x64 host. 4 NICs on host.

VLAN set up on private range eg ip 10.2.0.122, vlan ID 10 on NIC 1.

Ping in and out fine.

Run VM guest, bridged, on host's NIC 4.  The guests NIC 1 is DHCP.  Can ping in and out.

SWitch DHCP off i nguest, I set up vlan0 in the guest with public IP eg 194.44.80.145 with vlan id 11, now can't ping in/out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a VLAN on the HOST! and have the guests use that/bridge off that in the Virtual Guest settings (VMWare would use VMNETn, may have to edit VMware networking config manually as the GUI in version 8 of workstation doesn't allow you).  In the guest OS it should just have a static IP as normal, no vlan setup.